# Database performance for determining entities assigned to users

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

**I am interested in insight in improving performance in the following instance:**

I am currently working on an application that has a hierarchical entity structure where, depending on a user’s level within the organization, they would have an assignment to specific entity at a specific level – and thereby have access to all their children (in this case buildings within districts within regions throughout the U.S.). Most of the super users will have upward of 20,000 individual entities in their portfolio, some with as many as 40,000.

Instead of going into great detail, let’s suffice to say that a good bit of logic is needed to determine all the entities a user has access to. This logic is currently handled using a table function that is used in 95% of the stored procedures. The average stored procedure takes no more than 1 - 2 seconds to run. BUT, in an ASP.Net page that makes calls to 10+ different stored procedures, the performance hit quickly snowballs into 20+ seconds.

As an alternative, we were thinking of only calling this table function once (upon log in) and storing the results in a table (after clearing out any previous values for the same user). We would then have all the stored procedures reference this new table instead of the table function. A test revealed that a page which took 15 seconds to load could render in less than 3 seconds when selecting from the new table.

For example:

1. User logs in
2. system deletes all entities for the user in the table
3. system inserts all the user’s entities then
4. system sends them on their merry way and no longer runs the table function for that current session

**Our concern is that, with the potential for hundreds of users consistently logging in and out of the application, deleting from and inserting into this table so often could result in a significant performance hit itself due to row level locking. Has anyone else used a SQL Table in such a manner? If so, should we be concerned with low performance due to the constant inserting and deleting from a single table.**

Comment: Is this something you can store in memory for each user, in the session?

Comment: I want to keep it in the DB to avoid having to add params to all the stored procs. It would save sooo much time to just make a new table and point the current function at it.

Answer (score 2):

I have done something similar and it was fine but it was for an app with at most a few hundred concurrent users so it depends on what kind of scale you have. If you get deadlocks you could take it once step further by creating and dropping a table for each user but you would have to have something that dropped the table when a user's session expired.

Both of the above are a bit of a hack what you really should do is maintain a user permisions table and update it when the associated data changes.  Might be a major bit of re factoring though depending on your application.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be a bad design, and you will hit performance issues at some point.

I can think of two ways to turn this problem on it's head, first how often do you really need a list of all the entities that a user can access, it would be much faster to recurse up the tree with a CTE and check the permission for the record they want to access, but this is a big change in your model.

The second is not to update the cache when the user logs on, but when the data is changed. Have a trigger on the assignment table, whenever this data changes apply the result of this change to the permitted items table, effectively cascading the change all the way down the tree. Because the data would be changing only when necessary it would be more performant.